# Enable DRM_KMS_CMA_HELPER in linux kernel

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to recompile my Linux Kernel 3.18 with DRM_KMS_CMA_HELPER enabled, but editing the .config file is not working.

I have the dependencies enabled, but it still shows and not enabled.

Is there a way i can do this without editing the Kconfig file? Do i need to enable any special module for it to work?

Thanks for your help, Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because building customized kernels is off-topic at this site.

Comment: @Pilot6: I think it's on topic to discuss how to *build* custom kernels but actually *running* them is unsupported.